# ListView doesn't erase old text, only overlay the new

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm following the Sunshine tutorial on udacity, here comes my problem:

I have a ListView with some items, taken from an ArrayAdapter:

```
List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));
mForecastAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),
                        R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, 
                        weekForecast);
listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
```

And in another function, as a background task, I update my Adapter:

```
if (result != null) {
   mForecastAdapter.clear();
   for(String dayForecastStr : result) {
      mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
   }
   mForecastAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         
}
```

But for some reason, I get these results:

[image: before updating]
[image: After updating]

Anyone know a solution?

---

UPDATE:
weekForecast was a method variable, I declared it to be a class variable, now my update method is:

```
if (result != null) {
   weekForecast.clear();
   mForecastAdapter.clear();
   for(String dayForecastStr : result) {
      mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
   }
   mForecastAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         
}
```

### ----------

UPDATE2:

I got the solution, the problem was not caused by any procedure/variable in the class.
That was a layout problem! I was using a `<fragment>` as main tag in layout.xml file instead of a `<FrameLayout>`

Comment: are you using fragments?

Comment: Yes, I'm following step by step the online tutorial

Comment: then you have probably two fragments overlapping. One declared static in your layout and the second add through a transaction

Comment: So how can I solve this?

Comment: if that is the case get rid of one of it.

Comment: actually I inflate only 1 layout, so I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: are you or are you not adding a Fragment in your Activity programmatically ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109765/discussion-between-luca-nicoletti-and-blackbelt).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: set background color in the Listview, e.g. white.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, in fact, setting #FFFFFF as background in xml file, cause another problem: new data does not appear at all

Comment: This must be a comment !!

Answer (score 0):

Usually best practice is to make a `reset()` or call `clear()` function that clears data before applying new data with `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to work with the list `weekForecast` instead of changing the adapter. Try this code

```
if (result != null) {
   weekForecast.clear();
   for(String dayForecastStr : result) {
       weekForecast.add(dayForecastStr);
   }
   mForecastAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

UPD: If `weekForecast` is local for a method, make it a class variable

Comment: Already said I can't accett weekForecast where I do the updates

Comment: Is `weekForecast` in the same class where you update adapter?

Comment: I do the update inside a Inner class, tried to declare weekForecast as a class variable, and clearing it inside the update method, but it didn't solve the problem